# dynamodb, MobileHub not working

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-mobilehub

I followed these documents to set up a simple app using dynamoDB:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html
and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#add-aws-mobile-sdk-basic-setup

And then as a test I used the code provided to Create (Save) an Item.

Once ready to run the app, I get this error message:

```
Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" 
UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException, message=Supplied AttributeValue is empty, 
must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes}
```

After searching the net, I discovered there was a problem related to Swift 4.
And the solution seems to be adding *@objcMembers* in front of the classes automatically generated by AWS.

But for me it did not work. The error stays the same. I also tried to set the swift version to 3.3 instead of 4.1 (I only have these 2 versions available), this also did not fix the issue.

Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @Michel, Did you try adding the objc annotation at the class level or attribute level? Can you try both the methods described in the solution in the issue github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/750? Also, have you downloaded the models from AWS Mobile Hub?

Comment: Yes I did all that and it did not work (I suppose something else was wrong). I gave up and went to find some other examples on AWS to get started (DynamoDBSampleSwift inside aws-sdk-ios-samples-master) and this time it is finally working. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thank you! Can you share what worked and what you think was the error?

Comment: I just added an answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who runs into this in the future, if you are using Swift 4 and have downloaded the swift models from the AWS Mobile Hub, following the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#add-aws-mobile-sdk-basic-setup) then add the @objcMembers on top of the class definition line as shown below. This worked for me.

```
import AWSDynamoDB

@objcMembers
class TableName: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did to finally have something working and get started using dynamoDB:

I got [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) from GitHub.

Then I chose the DynamoDBSampleSwift project inside the archive. I was able to make it work without to much trouble.

I have no idea what was not working in my previous trial.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many things but finally, this worked. Add the `@objcMembers` on top of the class definition line as shown below.

```
import AWSDynamoDB

@objcMembers
class TableName: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
```

Thanks, Victor 'Chris' Cabral